# Multiple Calculations in a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, conditional, map, slot

I want to add and subtract 3 from a list.

pos = {82,84}

```
If[# > 3,
       (# - 3) && (# + 3)] & /@ pos
```

the output I want:

```
{79,85,81,87}
```

the output I get:

```
{79 && 85, 81 && 87}
```

Comment: `&&` is the same as `And`; you might want to use `List`, followed by `Sequence` instead.

Comment: `{#-3,#+3}&/@pos//Flatten`

Comment: What do you want to happen if  `x <=3`? Leave it there unmodified, or remove it from the list? If the first possibility, maybe `{1,2,3,82,85} /. x_ /; x > 3 -> {x-3,x+3}//Flatten`

Answer (score 3):

```
(* erase <=3 *)  
pos={1,2,3,82,84};
Cases[pos, x_?(# > 3 &) :> {x - 3, x + 3}] // Flatten


(* keep <=3 *)
pos={1,2,3,82,84};
pos /. x_?(# > 3 &) :> {x - 3, x + 3} // Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer suggested by [b.gates.you.know.what][1]

```
ifs = If[# > 3,
List[Sequence[# - 3, # + 3]]] & /@ pos
```

It works!!
[1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gates-you-know-what

Comment: This gives a lot of extraneous stuff in the output.

Answer (score -2):

```
Split[{79, 85, 81, 87}, 
 Abs[#1 - #2] == 6 || Abs[#1 - #2] == 3 || Abs[#1 - #2] == 0 &]
```